# I'm trying to make this code in vanilla javascript work in reactjs, but it's falling into the infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, oop

This is the code i got from codepen, it generates special characters and changes to the phrase i put, I'm wanting to compile this vanilla javascript code to react, because you can't use the DOM
there.

My real doubt is where do I put the useState so that it stops looping and shows character by character, this passing for example the state 'title' in a .

vanilla javascript code:

```
function setCharAt(str,index,chr) {
    if(index > str.length-1) return str;
    return str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
}

var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-=+<>,./?[{()}]!@#$%^&*~`\|'.split('');

var progress404 = 0;
var total404 = $('.text__error').data('text').length;

var progressLink = 0;
var totalLink = $('.text__link a').data('text').length;

var scrambleInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var string404 = $('.text__error').data('text');
    var stringLink = $('.text__link a').data('text');
    
    for(var i = 0; i < total404; i++) {
        if(i >= progress404) {
            string404 = setCharAt(string404, i, characters[Math.round(Math.random() * (characters.length - 1))]);
        } 
    }
    
    for(var i = 0; i < totalLink; i++) {
        if(i >= progressLink) {
            stringLink = setCharAt(stringLink, i, characters[Math.round(Math.random() * (characters.length - 1))]);
        } 
    }
    
    $('.text__error').text(string404);
    $('.text__link a').text(stringLink);
}, 1000 / 60);

setTimeout(function() {
    var revealInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if(progress404 < total404) {
            progress404++;
        }else if(progressLink < totalLink) {
            progressLink++;
        }else{
            clearInterval(revealInterval);
            clearInterval(scrambleInterval);
        }
    }, 50);
}, 1000);
```

This is the code I developed to try to work:

```
const [ title, setTitle ] = useState('404 page not found')
    const [ link, setLink ] = useState('click here to go home')

    function setCharAt(str: string,index: number,chr: any) {
        if(index > str.length-1) return str;
        return str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
    }
    
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-=+<>,./?[{()}]!@#$%^&*~`\|'.split('');
    
    var progress404 = 0;
    var total404 = title.length
    
    var progressLink = 0;
    var totalLink = link.length
    
    var scrambleInterval = setInterval(function() {
        
        for(var i = 0; i < total404; i++) {
            if(i >= progress404) {
                setTitle( setCharAt(title, i, characters[Math.round(Math.random() * (characters.length - 1))]));
            } 
        }
        
        for(var i = 0; i < totalLink; i++) {
            if(i >= progressLink) {
                setLink( setCharAt(link, i, characters[Math.round(Math.random() * (characters.length - 1))]));
            } 
        }

    }, 1000 / 60);

    setTimeout(function() {
        var revealInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if(progress404 < total404) {
                progress404++;
            }else if(progressLink < totalLink) {
                progressLink++;
            }else{
                clearInterval(revealInterval);
                clearInterval(scrambleInterval);
            }
        }, 50);
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Create that `setInterval` either in a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) or [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) with an empty array as dependency list (so it'll only ever run once). As written, you're creating new intervals every time the component renders. And then probably take some time read through the React tutorial.

Comment: could you describe it better? or even make the code

Comment: No, because that's literally what the React tutorial and docs were written for. They're really good: follow the tutorial, then read up on the specifics you're unclear on afterward.

Comment: Thanks man, I managed to solve it, I looked at the tutorial.